# How to style Rebass Switch

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, rebass

Using Rebass/Forms in react and I cannot properly resize the Switch component using styles properly. (I also am using `@emotion/styled`)

I have tried using a `size` attribute, but that does not give the desired effect of simply changing the scale of the switch.

I have tried using the `sx` property and giving it a `width` and a `height`, but that only resizes the button element and not the inner div which is the "sliding dot"

I know that I could write some styling targeting the inner div itself, but I would like to find a way to give it a height and width a single time and it apply to both the button and the inner div.

```
<Switch
  sx={{ width: "30px", height: "15px" }}
/>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/styling-rebass-switch-uu7wg

Comment: also looking at help applying color styles. `bg` and `color` don't have the effect you would assume.

Comment: What's your expectation regarding `color`?

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to do what you want 'out of the box' because the height and width are [hard coded in the source](https://github.com/rebassjs/rebass/blob/master/packages/forms/src/index.js#L338-L339)

Luckily the internals of `rebass` are very nice, so it's possible to create your own with a little copy-pasta from the rebass source code.

```js
import React from "react";
import { Box } from "reflexbox";

export const ResizableSwitch = ({
  checked,
  height = 24,
  width = 40,
  ...props
}) => (
  <Box
    as="button"
    type="button"
    role="switch"
    tx="forms"
    variant="switch"
    aria-checked={checked}
    {...props}
    __css={{
      appearance: "none",
      m: 0,
      p: 0,
      width,
      height,
      color: "primary",
      bg: "transparent",
      border: "1px solid",
      borderColor: "primary",
      borderRadius: 9999,
      "&[aria-checked=true]": {
        bg: "primary"
      },
      ":focus": {
        outline: "none",
        boxShadow: "0 0 0 2px"
      }
    }}
  >
    <Box
      aria-hidden
      style={{
        transform: checked ? `translateX(${width - height}px)` : "translateX(0)"
      }}
      sx={{
        mt: "-1px",
        ml: "-1px",
        width: height,
        height,
        borderRadius: 9999,
        border: "1px solid",
        borderColor: "primary",
        bg: "background",
        transitionProperty: "transform",
        transitionTimingFunction: "ease-out",
        transitionDuration: "0.1s",
        variant: "forms.switch.thumb"
      }}
    />
  </Box>
);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/styling-rebass-switch-r6tmx?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you for the solution, I will just make my own rendition of the component and then be able to use it how I want to. I guess you made it 400px wide in the example just to show that you could, lol

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't. I took a deep look into the package itself and it seems like there is no fixed rule for the components written in this package. Some component do get the `props` and the `sx`. But there are components, like `switch` that hosts another component as a children, and no prop passed to it.

If you take a look at the implementation of `switch` [in this page here](https://github.com/rebassjs/rebass/blob/master/packages/forms/src/index.js):

```
export const Switch = forwardRef(({
  checked,
  ...props
}, ref) =>
  <Box
    ref={ref}
    as='button'
    type='button'
    role='switch'
    tx='forms'
    variant='switch'
    aria-checked={checked}
    {...props}
    __css={{
      appearance: 'none',
      m: 0,
      p: 0,
      width: 40,
      height: 24,
      color: 'primary',
      bg: 'transparent',
      border: '1px solid',
      borderColor: 'primary',
      borderRadius: 9999,
      '&[aria-checked=true]': {
        bg: 'primary',
      },
      ':focus': {
        outline: 'none',
        boxShadow: '0 0 0 2px'
      },
    }}>
    <Box
      aria-hidden
      style={{
        transform: checked ? 'translateX(16px)' : 'translateX(0)',
      }}
      sx={{
        mt: '-1px',
        ml: '-1px',
        width: 24,
        height: 24,
        borderRadius: 9999,
        border: '1px solid',
        borderColor: 'primary',
        bg: 'background',
        transitionProperty: 'transform',
        transitionTimingFunction: 'ease-out',
        transitionDuration: '0.1s',
        variant: 'forms.switch.thumb',
      }}
    />
  </Box>
)
```

There are 2 `Box` components (which are the base component of the package), one is a children of the other. The first `Box` is the area of the switch, and the child `Box` is the circle/button you are looking for, If you take a look on this component, you will see there is no outside variable that passed to it, so nothing can be changed - the style is already written.

This is the Button/Circle component:

```
    <Box
      aria-hidden
      style={{
        transform: checked ? 'translateX(16px)' : 'translateX(0)',
      }}
      sx={{
        mt: '-1px',
        ml: '-1px',
        width: 24,
        height: 24,
        borderRadius: 9999,
        border: '1px solid',
        borderColor: 'primary',
        bg: 'background',
        transitionProperty: 'transform',
        transitionTimingFunction: 'ease-out',
        transitionDuration: '0.1s',
        variant: 'forms.switch.thumb',
      }}
    />
```

If you are still willing to use that package, you can overcome this by overwriting the css, giving the component a className and apply styling to its children.

Plus, you can open an [issue](https://github.com/rebassjs/rebass/issues) or suggest a fix on the package github repository.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [Switch source code](https://github.com/rebassjs/rebass/blob/master/packages/forms/src/index.js#L321) it seems no properties are propagated to the inner `<div>`... would you open an issue?

In the mean while you can set css properties for children and/or based on attributes:

```
.myswitch {
  width: 30px !important;
  height: 15px !important;
  background: gray !important;
}

.myswitch[aria-checked="true"] {
  background: red !important;
}

.myswitch div {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: red;
}
```

then:

```
<Switch className="myswitch" />
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/styling-rebass-switch-o0j8t

Comment: Hi @amaster , can I ask you some feedback about my answer?

Comment: It is a viable solution but is hard coded CSS :( when I am trying to use a theme file and do some tweaking within components. So not the answer I am looking for, but a good answer nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS transform scale to scale down/up an element and it's children. As, you're using emotion, here's something that goes along with it.

[scale documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale)

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/styling-rebass-switch-5fqku?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
import { Label, Checkbox, Switch } from "@rebass/forms";

const Title = styled.h1`
  text-align: center;
`;

const FormLabel = styled(Label)`
  align-items: center;
`;

const Control = styled.div`
  width: 40px;
`;

const Toggle = styled(Switch)`
  transform: scale(.7)
`;


export default function App() {
  const [switched, setSwitched] = useState(false);
  const toggleSwitch = () => {
    setSwitched(!switched);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Title>How to Style Rebass/Forms Switch</Title>
      <FormLabel sx={{ padding: "10px" }}>
        <Control>
          <Checkbox size="16px" sx={{ marginLeft: "10px" }} />
        </Control>
        CheckBox
      </FormLabel>
      <FormLabel sx={{ padding: "10px" }}>
        <Control>
          <Toggle
            checked={switched}
            onClick={() => toggleSwitch()}
          />
        </Control>
        Switch
      </FormLabel>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @amaster, background color works for me https://codesandbox.io/s/styling-rebass-switch-5fqku?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

https://codesandbox.io/s/styling-rebass-switch-zto4z?file=/src/styles.css:37-1020

```
button.switch,
button.switch:hover,
button.switch:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  box-shadow: none;
}

button.switch > div {
  content: "";
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background-color: #9fa2ab;
}

button.switch > div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: -2px;
  top: -3px;
  transition: left 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease, box-shadow 0.1s ease,
    transform 0.1s ease;
  background-color: #5b5c60;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
    0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
    0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

button.switch[aria-checked="true"] {
  background-color: #d0f35e;
}
button.switch[aria-checked="true"] > div:after {
  background-color: #86af00;
}
button.switch[aria-checked="false"] {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  left: 18px;
}
```

Add class switch

```
<Switch
            
            className="switch"
            sx={{ width: "30px", height: "15px" }}
            checked={switched}
            onClick={() => toggleSwitch()}
          />
```